# Does Typescript have static imports?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose `Object` is something that is importable and we currently use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.  Could we do:

```
 import {getOwnPropertyNames} from 'Object';
```

Comment: No. RxJS suffered this problem for years, and it had to import methods like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`. Now it switched into the `pipe` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TypeScript uses the ES2015 concept of modules ([more here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)), but `Object` isn't a module, so you can't do what you've shown, but you can use destructuring assignment instead:

```
const { getOwnPropertyNames } = Object;
```

...which is the same as:

```
const getOwnPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames;
```

For any method that doesn't rely on a particular `this` value (and the [ones on `Object`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-object-constructor) don't), you could use the result on its own:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
const { getOwnPropertyNames } = Object;
console.log(getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
```

Comment: Is there a `const { * } = Object` syntax, to "static import" all functions from `Object`?

Comment: @LukasEder - No, there aren't any wildcards in destructuring. (Yet? Though I haven't even seen talk of them.)